# CALayer's shouldRasterize vs UIView's drawRect?

Tags: ios

Even though the two APIs are at different levels of the stack, both CALayer's shouldRasterize and UIView's drawRect: achieve the same goal - render the bitmap and cache it for future reuse. In both cases, the cached versions are invalidated if the view/layer needs redrawn. The only difference I perceive is how the bitmap is drawn. drawRect: is done using the CPU, and CALayer's shouldRasterize is done by whatever Core Animation chooses to use, likely the GPU.

Can people comment on any additional difference between the two APIs?

Comment: Is there a question here? :)

Answer (score 1):

`shouldRasterize` caches the drawn layer *and all of its sublayers* into a single bitmap context. `drawRect` just provides bitmap content for an individual layer.

Note that setting `shouldRasterize` on the layer does not affect how the layer is drawn; it affects what happens *after* those pixels are drawn. You can use these options independently or together; they provide different functionality.